# Plot data with labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

My data is stored in a python list like this :

```
data = [['N','0'],['1','4'],['2','8'],['3','12'],['N','1'],['1','3'],['2','6'],['3','9'],['N','2'],['1','2'],['2','4'],['3','6']]
```

The sublists `['N','?']` with `'?'` being `'0','1','2'` indicates a new set of data. The sublists following it are a set of (x,y) data that I would like to plot using lines. The figure should show three increasing lines with slope 4,3, and 2 respectively. I also want to put a label on each curve, which would be the number `'?'` in the sublists `['N','?']`.

How can I do so using python and matplotib ?

Comment: This isn't a code writing service... You'll get better results here if you share some code that you tried so far, and give details of what is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a significantly better data representation in order to do this. I would do the following please comment if the np slicing is confusing.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = [['N','0'],['1','4'],['2','8'],['3','12'],['N','1'],['1','3'],['2','6'],['3','9'],['N','2'],['1','2'],['2','4'],['3','6']]
# Dictionary with Nx as keys and corresponding plots as values
plot_dict = {}
curkey = None
for x, y in data:
    # Adding a new key
    if x == 'N':
        curkey = x + y
        plot_dict[curkey] = []
    # Add corresponding values to key
    elif curkey in plot_dict:
        # Cast as integers for plots
        plot_dict[curkey].append(map(int,(x,y)))

lines = []
names = []
for name, vals in plot_dict.items():
    # np.array(vals)[:,0] gets the first column so the x data
    # np.array(vals)[:,1] gets the second column of vals (y data)
    lines.append(plt.plot(np.array(vals)[:,0], np.array(vals)[:,1])[0])
    names.append(name)
plt.legend(lines, names)
plt.show()
```

it should yield the following:
[image: carries out this plot]